# putting scrollable content with webview . Is there a solution?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-nestedscrollview

I am searching from fews days about how to put WebView inside NestedSrollView but there is not a single correct solution . Putting WebView inside NestedScrollView has incorrect height issue . Is there any way to put views like textview , imageview that can be scrolled along with webview data ?

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@color/alpha_color"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="12dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Game Title"
                android:padding="0dp"
                style="@style/cardview_textstyle"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary" />

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/myRatingBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                android:isIndicator="true" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:background="@color/accent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/cardview_textstyle"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="Summary"
            android:layout_margin="12dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/deck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"

            />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:background="@color/accent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reviewer_field"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Reviewer :  "
                style="@style/SubTitleText"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reviewer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="-"
                android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/reviewer_field"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/reviewer_field"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                 />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_field"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Publish Date :  "
                style="@style/SubTitleText"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/reviewer_field"
               />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="-"
                android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/date_field"
                android:layout_below="@id/reviewer"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/date_field"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                />


        </RelativeLayout>


        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:background="@color/accent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            />


    </LinearLayout>

        <com.example.randomlocks.gamesnote.HelperClass.CustomView.AVLoadingIndicatorView
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:indicator="Pacman"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            app:indicator_color="@color/accent" />


    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: use nestedview inside the coordinator layout

Comment: I am using it inside coordinator layout . Didn't posted the entire xml

Comment: ok then use Linear layout inside your NestedScrollView and put your views and give them layout_ayweight

Comment: Refer to this post, http://stackoverflow.com/q/43533068/6521116.